# Unable to connect directus docker image to remote postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, docker, directus

I am trying to run directus/directus:v9.0.0-rc.19 docker image in local that connects to remote postgres DB. I get the admin login page http://localhost:8055/admin/login but I can't login with DIRECTUS_INSTALL_EMAIL, it says 'Wrong username or password', I tried to reset the password as well but that didn't work either even after setting correct smtp details in docker compose yaml. I am using below docker compose file. The user account already exists in postgres db I am trying to connect to. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```
version: "3"

networks:
  directus:

services:
  directus:
    image: directus/directus:v9.0.0-rc.19
    ports:
      - "8055:8055"
    environment:
      DIRECTUS_APP_ENV: "production"
      DIRECTUS_AUTH_PUBLICKEY: "3c34db10-f565-0934-8536-gfds89743h98"
      DIRECTUS_AUTH_SECRETKEY: "FofptWoigjhfdoigzUx2Kv49xpio0G2"
      DIRECTUS_DATABASE_TYPE: "postgresql"
      DIRECTUS_DATABASE_HOST: "<postgres server address>"
      DIRECTUS_DATABASE_PORT: "5432"
      DIRECTUS_DATABASE_NAME: "directus-cms2"
      DIRECTUS_DATABASE_USERNAME: "<postgres user>"
      DIRECTUS_DATABASE_PASSWORD: "<Postgres pwd>"
      DIRECTUS_MAIL_DEFAULT_TRANSPORT: "smtp"
      DIRECTUS_MAIL_DEFAULT_FROM: "<from-address>"
      DIRECTUS_MAIL_DEFAULT_HOST: "<smtp-host>"
      DIRECTUS_MAIL_DEFAULT_PORT: "587"
      DIRECTUS_MAIL_DEFAULT_USERNAME: "<smtp-user>"
      DIRECTUS_MAIL_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "<smtp-password>"
      DIRECTUS_MAIL_DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION: "ssl"
      DIRECTUS_INSTALL_EMAIL:  "<my email>"
      DIRECTUS_INSTALL_PASSWORD: "<password>"
    volumes:
      - ./data/config:/var/directus/config
      - ./data/uploads:/var/directus/public/uploads    
    networks:
      - directus
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: I had posted question on GitHub discussion forum for directus and received answer there. In nutshell, I was using wrong environment variables, correct page to refer is at - https://docs.directus.io/reference/environment-variables.html

See below, for answer on github -
https://github.com/directus/directus/discussions/3269

Comment: note first link is dead